# no entry into parent table but "0" or "blank" insert into FK in child table

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hi guys I am trying to solve one problem with inserting data to Parent - Child tables. Tables below and also ERR diagram show a structure and PK/FK keys. I am inserting data from webform and PHP is used to capture data and pass it to the database. 
Fields in mainTable - F_Name, L_Name and Email are just input textfields, 
fields in college tables are checkboxes.

Imagine that one teacher can teach at one, two or three colleges where he checks the checkbox for each college/school where he is teaching. But if he teaches only at one college there is when my problem comes. As all of the "college" tables are linked to "Teacher" with PK/FK.

My question is, is there any way how to store auto generated College ID's if for example teacher is teaching only at one college. At the moment with my PHP it fails and I don't know how to fix it.

I have a example of my PHP under the Schema structure. Just a small note that connection to database works properly.

If this or similar was already asked I do appologize.

Thanks for any tips.

```
-------------------------------------------------------
-- Schema test
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `test` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 ;
USE `test` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `test`.`CollegeA`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`CollegeA` (
  `CollegeAID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SchoolA` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `SchoolB` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `SchoolC` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CollegeAID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `test`.`CollegeB`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`CollegeB` (
  `CollegeBID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `School1` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `School2` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `School3` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CollegeBID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `test`.`CollegeC`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`CollegeC` (
  `CollegeCID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `School11` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `School22` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `School33` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CollegeCID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `test`.`Teacher`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`Teacher` (
  `TeacherId` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `F_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `L_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `CollegeAID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `CollegeBID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `CollegeCID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`MainId`),
  INDEX `CollegeAID_idx` (`CollegeAID` ASC),
  INDEX `CollegeBID_idx` (`CollegeBID` ASC),
  INDEX `CollegeCID_idx` (`CollegeCID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `CollegeAID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CollegeAID`)
    REFERENCES `test`.`CollegeA` (`CollegeAID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `CollegeBID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CollegeBID`)
    REFERENCES `test`.`CollegeB` (`CollegeBID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `CollegeCID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CollegeCID`)
    REFERENCES `test`.`CollegeC` (`CollegeCID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

[image]

PHP example

```
if(empty($SchoolA) && empty($SchoolB) && empty($SchoolC)){

    $CollegeAId = "";

        }
        else {
            $queryCOLLEGEA = "
                INSERT INTO CollegeA (SchoolA, SchoolB, SchoolC)
VALUES('$SchoolA','$SchoolB','$SchoolC')";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $queryCOLLEGEA);    
                $CollegeAId = mysqli_insert_id($con);
            };

if(empty($School1) && empty($School2) && empty($School3)){

    $CollegeBId = "";

        }
        else {
            $queryCOLLEGEB = "
                INSERT INTO CollegeB (School1, School2, School3)
VALUES('$School1','$School2','$School3')";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $queryCOLLEGEB);    
                $CollegeBId = mysqli_insert_id($con);
            };

 if(empty($School11) && empty($School22) && empty($School33)){

    $CollegeCId = "";

        }
        else {
            $queryCOLLEGEC = "
                INSERT INTO CollegeB (School11, School22, School33)
VALUES('$School11','$School22','$School33')";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $queryCOLLEGEC);    
                $CollegeCId = mysqli_insert_id($con);
            };

$queryMain = "
INSERT INTO Teacher (F_Name, L_Name, Email, CollegeAID, CollegeBID, CollegeCID) 
VALUES ('$F_Name', '$L_Name', '$Email', '$CollegeAId', '$CollegeBId', '$CollegeCId')";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $queryMain);
```

Comment: Why do you need 3 tables to store the same thing?

Comment: I think it is easier to have it the way as it is. Imagine there is 3 Colleges and each has minimum of 10 schools. Table would have to many columns i think

Comment: Why not have "College - College_Schools - School" as a relationship? That way, you'll have 3 rows in College, and match each of those rows to their corresponding schools.

Comment: I am sure it can be done that way too, however this was only small example from much bigger database which already is in place and I don't think I want to change it as I don't make decisions. Thank you for suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `NOT NULL` column as foreign key. In this case you cannot leave it empty, you must set here correct key from referenced table. You can change table definition to

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`Teacher` (
  `TeacherId` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `F_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `L_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `CollegeAID` INT(11),
  `CollegeBID` INT(11),
  `CollegeCID` INT(11),
  PRIMARY KEY (`MainId`),
  INDEX `CollegeAID_idx` (`CollegeAID` ASC),
  INDEX `CollegeBID_idx` (`CollegeBID` ASC),
  INDEX `CollegeCID_idx` (`CollegeCID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `CollegeAID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CollegeAID`)
    REFERENCES `test`.`CollegeA` (`CollegeAID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `CollegeBID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CollegeBID`)
    REFERENCES `test`.`CollegeB` (`CollegeBID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `CollegeCID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CollegeCID`)
    REFERENCES `test`.`CollegeC` (`CollegeCID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;
```

In this table you can insert NULL values into CollegeAID, CollegeBID and CollegeCID. So, if teacher works in college, it will have value in appropriate CollegeID. If no - CollegeID will be NULL.

Also you will ned to change your code. Change you code like this

```php
if(empty($SchoolA) && empty($SchoolB) && empty($SchoolC)){
    $CollegeAId = null;
}
```

for all three colleges. You need null, not empty string.

And another change is needed here

```php
$queryMain = "
    INSERT INTO Teacher (F_Name, L_Name, Email, CollegeAID, CollegeBID, CollegeCID) 
    VALUES ('$F_Name', '$L_Name', '$Email', '$CollegeAId', '$CollegeBId', '$CollegeCId')";
```

Variable $CollegeAId now contains proper NULL value. But this query will be produced into

```sql
INSERT INTO Teacher (F_Name, L_Name, Email, CollegeAID, CollegeBID, CollegeCID) 
VALUES ('F_Name', 'L_Name', 'Email', '', 'CollegeBId', 'CollegeCId')
```

See it? Still empty string instead of NULL! You need to change query string. It must looks like

```sql
INSERT INTO Teacher (F_Name, L_Name, Email, CollegeAID, CollegeBID, CollegeCID) 
VALUES ('F_Name', 'L_Name', 'Email', NULL, 'CollegeBId', 'CollegeCId')
```

For example, you can do it this way for college A:

```php
$CollegeAId = isset($CollegeAId) ? "'$CollegeAId'" : 'NULL';
$queryMain = "
    INSERT INTO Teacher (F_Name, L_Name, Email, CollegeAID, CollegeBID, CollegeCID) 
    VALUES ('$F_Name', '$L_Name', '$Email', $CollegeAId, '$CollegeBId', '$CollegeCId')";
```

Comment: Hi, I have updated table definition as suggested, but it is still not successful. So if I choose only one college/school then it fails to pull CollegeID and store it into Teacher table. It will be stored in appropriate College Table.

Comment: Thank you for your tips, I have again updated code as suggested but no luck. When checking all colleges it is working, but as soon as one is left not checked submission fails.

Comment: OK, I wrote almost full example :-) Last error is in query string. You need to change it to create correct SQL.

Comment: thank you for your help. I have overlooked that there is NO single '' around "$College...ID" and that is why it was failing. Going through your suggestion again helped a lot. Thank you again!!

Comment: can I have one question, would this approach work for file upload? Lets say, there is an option to add files but does not have to be uploaded. There is a table for files to be uploaded. Up to 4. If uploaded, it generates new ID but if no upload it should not make any entries in the table.